# JS not parsing Date correctly on production server

Tags: javascript, ajax, date, parsing

I get my data from the db using ajax, I'm using those 2 lines of code to display the date in an input `Date` :

```
var dateReceptionDE = new Date(tache.dateReceptionDE); 
console.log("From DB : " + tache.dateReceptionDE);
console.log("In the variable: " + dateReceptionDE);
document.getElementById("ReceiveEDDateEdit").valueAsDate = new 
           Date(dateReceptionDE.getFullYear(),dateReceptionDE.getMonth(),dateReceptionDE.getDate(),12);
```

This is the result in the localhost : 
[image: Result on console]

But when I deploy it in the production server, I get this: 
[image]

[image]

PS 1: I'm working on a project using MySql (as a DB), JEE (as Back-end) and JS.

PS 2: Date type in DB is DATETIME, I tried DATE but still the same result.

PS 3: Tomcat version is 8.5.43 (Both local and prod server)

**UPDATE :** 
I forget to mention that I'm using also json between java servlet and js.

```
Object task= tacheDao.selectREQUEST();

        String json = new Gson().toJson(task);

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(json);
```

AJAX :

```
var task= JSON.parse(data);
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not just send the date as an ISO 8601 string? It's a standard for a reason - to be used.

Comment: Because I have Html input as Date

Comment: `Date` reads ISO 8601 strings an it's actually one of the very few formats that is guaranteed to be parsed correctly

Comment: @VLAZ please how can I convert string generated by JSON to this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by modifying GSON Format Date in JSON object :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
String json =  gson.toJson(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that is not working in live is because your MySQL query is returning a date string that can't be parsed by JS immediately. In your SQL query, try formatting the date column, something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumnName, "%m/%d/%Y") AS dateReceptionDE FROM Table_Name;
```

Comment: This is an invalid date format and parsing it will be implementation dependant in JavaScript.

Comment: @VLAZ What do you mean by invalid date format? Do you mean that the "%m/%d/%Y" format is an invalid date format in JS?

Comment: [Yes, the parsing of this format will be platform dependant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Description)

Comment: It dosen't work ... I think the problem is with JSON, it parses the Date to String and give me this format "déc. 31, 2019"